# Speech recognition only listens for Commands in my dictionary?

Tags: c#

Okay so i am working on my program. The problem is that whenever spymode = true, it doesnt register whatever i am saying to the text file. It just registers the set commands in "CommandsList" dictionary. So whenever i say like "twitch" which is a command in that dictionary it will write that to the spymodeLog.txt file. But whenever i say something that is not a command, for example "hello my name is Robin" , that will not be written to the .txt file. It only takes commands in my dictionary and outputs it to the file whenever i say them. Why is this? and how can i fix it? really odd.

```
    static Dictionary<string, string> CommandsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    internal static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (keyHold == true)
        {
            string command = "";
            if (CommandsList.TryGetValue(e.Result.Text, out command))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(command);
            }
        }

        if (spymode == true)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string path = Application.StartupPath + "spymodeLog.txt";

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    wr.WriteLine(e.Result.Text.ToString());
                }
            }
            else if(!File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (var wr = new StreamWriter("spymodeLog.txt", true))
                {
                    wr.WriteLine(e.Result.Text.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: AFAIK SpeechRecognized is only called when it recognize an item from the dictionnary of commands

Comment: hmm okay , how do i do so that it get called from somethging that is not in the commandslist?

Answer (score 0):

SpeechRecognized event fire when a command from the dictionnary has been recognized, hence the name of the event.

What you want is the [SpeechDetected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechdetected(v=vs.110).aspx) event which from the help says it fire when it recognize something has been said.

> Each speech recognizer **has an algorithm to distinguish between silence and speech**. When the SpeechRecognitionEngine performs a speech recognition operation, **it raises the SpeechDetected event when its algorithm identifies the input as speech**.

This event will allow you to get the actual position when an audio was captured. This allow you to go find that audio portion and save it to a file or send it in the methods that allow you to convert audio to text (i do not remember the methods but they are there, i have used it in the past)

Second method which doesn't work on everyone computer. 1 out of 3 of my PC actually works with this method and this method is to create an instance of a special grammar disctionnary called `DictationGrammar`

What you do is create a new instance of this class. You have 3 ways to do so, either normal, spelling or default of the computer accessbility option.

default computer accessibility :

```
var grammar = new DictationGrammar();
```

Normal :

```
var grammar = new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation");
```

Spelling :

```
var grammar = new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation#spelling");
```

than use that dictionnary with the combinaison of all those you want and you can create a tree of choices that lead to the generic recognition. Me in my old app i used to have the keyword "Note" that had to be said and then it was falling on the `DictationGrammar` and started to recognize all text.

Since it didn't work on all computers while other commands where perfectly working i assumed it has something to do with wrong language of dictation grammar being loaded or something like that but there was no option to change that so i went with `SpeechDetected` and converted the audio to text myself.

Comment: hmm okay but in that example they also use SpeechReogniozed as the main handller? i dont see why it cant take any input? I see that the event is bound to the grammar handler but i just dont see how to make the engine take any input ? because the speechdetected is in that example exactly the same as my audiostatechange. Do i then have to input every american word in the grammar for it to work?

Comment: the sample just show multiple handlers so their sample can do many things. You are not forced to use all handlers of an object. just une those you need. The `SpeechDetected` event give you the AudioPosition in the eventargs where the detection was found. Then there must be some properties in the speech recognition object that you can gather what was said in the said timespan.

Comment: hmm okay , So if i want to log exactly anything that is being said to the .txt file, how do i do that? cuz basicly i just want something that can take whatever was said and just write to that file, the write part i know myself but how do i set up that event so it just takes whatever that was said?

Comment: for that windows already have built in speech-to-text. When it's on it writes whatever you say in the textbox / text control you have focused. [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17208/windows-10-use-speech-recognition) is how you enable it.

Comment: but i want it in my program :/Y

Comment: @Weirdrandom check second solution. First one works all the time but require more work and second one much easier (1 liner) but doesn't work on all computer.

Comment: hmm okay, ye i tried the "new dictationgrammar();" but that just outputed random sentences :D , not even close to what i was saying : ), do you have anything left from your old program where you converted audio to text?

Comment: this means you very likely have it implemented CORRECTLY. The thing is that speech recognition on the dictation you have to say it word by word with time in between. That is simply how it works. You have a tutorial that teach you how to do it in you config panel where you can activate text to speech and speech to text. I do believe that you can adjust your recognizer to your voice that help recognizing much better. It also show you how you must say the words so they register correctly and how to make them write to text software. At best i got around 90% recognition. Cortana is probably better.